# Symfony2 using Backbone.js and WSSE for authentication

Tags: php, symfony, backbone.js, fosrestbundle

I developed a REST-ful web application using FOSRestBundle and I want to use Backbone.js for the frontend. I am wondering about the authentication using tokens. I know that OAuth is only for an exchange server to server but for the front-end of my application how do I manage it? I read a lot on the forums and I know there WSSE method but how do I integrate with Backbone.js?

Also, what would be the best setup (firewalls) so that eventually I can integrate OAuth application? How to manage all those authetication protocols?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a normal login page with twig, then once you are successfully authenticated, redirect to a controller that renders a twig file containing backbone.js and any other client side resources, backbone can then take over from there as all your REST end points will be accessible if you have set up permissions correctly.

Comment: Sounds good but how is it gonna work when I'll have the FOSOAuthServerBundle in place ? I mean, how the system will manage authentication when I have FOSOAuthBundle up?

Comment: What about cases where your session has timed out because you haven't used your app for a while? It would redirect you out of your webapp, you'd have to load your entire app again once logged in, you'd loose the ability to replay actions that failed because of the 403 etc. etc.. 
I think the initial idea to handle API authentication via WWSE is not a bad one at all.

Comment: If it's been inactive for long enough that the session timed out it's a problem no matter what way you do it. Rather than return the login page HTML, return a friendly 403 with a JSON body that the client can read so it knows to re-authenticate then request the page you were on.